# Matrix optimization to maximise coverage

Tags: matrices, optimization

Apologies if I am framing the question wrong, but I am trying to solve the following problem.

I have a dataset in excel with companies going down and various indicators across the columns. I am trying to maximise "matrix" to ensure that all companies in my matrix have each indicator cell will be filled.

to provide some context, not every indicator has a value for each company, so I am trying to get the maximum coverage.

could someone please explain the best way to do this in either excel or R

I hope I have not lost anyone.

thanks

Comment: So is the problem that you're missing some indicators, or what is the problem? What do you mean precisely by "maximising the matrix"?

Comment: This really is not a Maths question, but I am happy to help. Create a new column at the far right. Use "countifblank() to identify the number of cells that are empty. Sort the companies on this column (increasing size). You will have a list of companies going from those with no blanks (all cells filled in) down to those with lots of blanks. Delete all the rows where the the number of blank cells is greater than zero.

Comment: sorry: countblank() not countifblank()

Comment: Hello, I think it is more complicated than that, since we can delete rows and columns to get the maximum coverage (i.e. every cell is filled with data)